# Spring 3 MVC example not running in Apache Tomcat 7.0

Tags: web-applications, spring-mvc

So basically I am trying to run a basic Spring 3 MVC example on my system. The example however is quiet stubborn. I am following the steps mentioned here: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-3-mvc-create-hello-world-application-spring-3-mvc/

It looks okay to me mapping wise. However when I run it on Apache Tomcat 7.0 in eclipse or in the Tomcat server directly I get the following error:

```
**type** Status report

**message** /Spring3MVC/

**description** The requested resource is not available.
```

The console log looks like this:

```
Dec 5, 2012 1:13:04 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:/Program Files/Java/jre6/bin/client;C:/Program Files/Java/jre6/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre6/lib/i386;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files\Intel\DMIX;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;D:\apache-maven-2.2.1\bin;.
Dec 5, 2012 1:13:04 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:Spring3MVC' did not find a matching property.
Dec 5, 2012 1:13:04 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Dec 5, 2012 1:13:04 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Dec 5, 2012 1:13:04 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 402 ms
Dec 5, 2012 1:13:04 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Dec 5, 2012 1:13:04 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.33
Dec 5, 2012 1:13:05 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://www.springframework.org/tags/form is already defined
Dec 5, 2012 1:13:05 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://www.springframework.org/tags is already defined
Dec 5, 2012 1:13:05 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
Dec 5, 2012 1:13:05 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'spring'
Dec 5, 2012 1:13:05 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'spring': initialization started
Dec 5, 2012 1:13:05 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'spring-servlet': startup date [Wed Dec 05 13:13:05 IST 2012]; root of context hierarchy
Dec 5, 2012 1:13:06 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]
Dec 5, 2012 1:13:06 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@a0219e: defining beans [helloWorldController,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,viewResolver,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor]; root of factory hierarchy
Dec 5, 2012 1:13:06 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/hello] onto handler 'helloWorldController'
Dec 5, 2012 1:13:06 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/hello.*] onto handler 'helloWorldController'
Dec 5, 2012 1:13:06 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/hello/] onto handler 'helloWorldController'
Dec 5, 2012 1:13:06 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'spring': initialization completed in 469 ms
Dec 5, 2012 1:13:06 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Dec 5, 2012 1:13:06 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Dec 5, 2012 1:13:06 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 1554 ms
```

The only thing I could see in this was the WARNING mentioned **atDec 5, 2012 1:13:04 PM**, but apparently that should not interfere with the application.

My web.xml at Web-INF/ is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>Spring3MVC</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

My spring-servlet.xml at Web-Inf/ is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans

http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd


http://www.springframework.org/schema/context


http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan
        base-package="net.viralpatel.spring3.controller" />

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

My helloWorldController is as follows:

```
package net.viralpatel.spring3.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class HelloWorldController {

    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public ModelAndView helloWorld() {

        String message = "Hello World, Spring 3.0!";
        return new ModelAndView("hello", "message", message);
    }
}
```

Finally my index.jsp is in Web-INF/ while my hello.jsp is in Web-INF/jsp

I am just starting off in Spring, but as far as I can tell this application should run. Also compared other examples on the web, and they have similar structures. Googling the error just says the mapping for the servlet is not there, which is not true. Hope someone out there has a solution to it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The app started working after I changed the spring-servlet name to dispatcher-servlet and made the corresponding changes in web.xml.

Answer (score 0):

You have define the *.html in web.xml. So you need to access it with URL hello.html or change the url-pattern to / only.